# How can i create a collection NFT? Metaplex isn't working its just throwing a 429 error

Tags: metaplex, solana-program, nft

So i have been trying to use Metaplex to create a Collection nft as i am trying to name my collection, and it is just loading and loading with nothing happening. I checked the Dev console and its throwing a 429 error. I have been told i can do what i am trying to do on metaplex with metaboss but i haven't been able to find any instructions on how to do so. Was wondering if somebody could give me a run down of how i can do this?

Will be much appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

metaboss is really easy to use you can install it from the installation guide [here](https://metaboss.rs/overview.html#recommended-way-to-install) and
the steps are pretty clear in this guide [here](https://metaboss.rs/collections.html) on how you can mint a Parent NFT and then update it on your NFT collection. If you get any technical questions on using it put them here to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the RPC that you are using complaining of too many requests. Similar to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018671/429-issues-on-solana-metaplex